# Press and Hold keyboard function

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, settings, keys

When I press and hold keys, for example "Backspase" It registers only one time and I have to press it repeatedly instead of just holding it. Same with other keys: numerals, space, letters etc.
When I'm in Windows everything works normal, but when i log in Linux, this function does not work.
I tried switching keyboards and It is all the same.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure keyboard repeat is enabled. You can do with the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat true
```